# How to display alert dialog on edittext click

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, onfocuschangelistener

How can i display alert dialog  when user touch on edittext.
I had already tried with onFocusChange() and OnClick() but not working properly as expected i had put some code also kindly help me.

```
ed2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus)
                {
                      getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                hideSoftKeyboard(btn_set_no);
                                showAlert();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

;

Comment: Make it on focus false and simple onclick to that edittext

Comment: not working .kindly help me

Comment: Yeah sure give me few mins

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Comment: not yet but working on it. i had done partially but it not display soft keyboard.

Comment: use ``onclick`` event

Comment: DonaldWu can you show me some demo. so i can better understand

Comment: i tried with onClick() but not working.

Answer (score 1):

hi can you try this,  **android:focusable="false"** in your edittext and make it simple click. Check this

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/ethome_click"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/profile_ic"
     android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
     android:hint="@string/search_source"
     android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base" />



@BindView(R.id.ethome_click)
EditText ethome_click;


@OnClick({R.id.ethome_click})
public void OnClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.ethome_click:

            showAlert();

            break;

    }
}
```